# Laravel query getting related data

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query (below) where i get product specifications list in edit page, so far it's working to return my data. The problem is i cannot get their parents info.

`Query`

```
$specs = DB::table('product_subspecification')
->where('product_id', '=', $product->id)
->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
->get();
```

`Result`

```
{#3106 ▼
  +"id": 8
  +"product_id": 15
  +"subspecification_id": 8
  +"title": "Xplorer 5500M"
  +"specification_id": 6
  +"status_id": 1
  +"created_at": "2018-08-06 12:42:40"
  +"updated_at": "2018-08-06 12:42:40"
}
```

## Issue

The issue is `Xplorer 5500M` is actually my sub-specification (which I saved it as my product specification and `it has parent` in this case is `Keyboard` I need to return that parent (Keyboard) name as well.

So later in my blade I will have something like:

```
+------------+---------------+
|   Parent   | Specification |
+------------+---------------+
|  Keyboard  | Xplorer 5500M |
+------------+---------------+
```

`Blade`

```
@foreach($specs as $spacsdf)
  <tr>
    <td>Parent name here</td>
    <td>{{$spacsdf->title}}</td>
    <td>Del Button</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

> PS: I've tried to join specifications table (is parents table name)
>   but all I got was `Keyboard` this time instead of `Xplorer 5500M`.

This was the second query I've tried:

```
$specs = DB::table('product_subspecification')
 ->where('product_id', '=', $product->id)
 ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
 ->join('specifications', 'specifications.id', '=', 'subspecifications.specification_id')
 ->get();
```

Any idea?

Comment: You want to leverage Eloquent to its full extent, please read the [documentation on relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships) first and after you try yourself come back and ask again.

Comment: @Kyslik please comment only if you have idea about the solution, i have the same approach with `x-editable` and my relations working perfectly the only matter is that i don't want to use x-editable in this particular part so I should somehow get the parent name base on their id as i mentioned in my second query. to prove that it is possible and I've done it see this https://ibb.co/feuZYz ]

Comment: First of all I will comment whenever I want and second of all I advice you to take a look at Eloquent instead of using query builder. This can be done in one line (apart of relation definition) and on top of that anyone fluent in Eloquent will understand it just by looking at it.

Comment: well thanks dude my problem has solved.

Comment: Good for you; bad for whoever is going to read it after you. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not specify which fields you would like to retrieve for a joined query, you might get some unwanted behaviour if you have equally named columns.

I would suggest trying to specify the fields you need with the "select" method:

```
$specs = DB::table('product_subspecification')
 ->select('product_subspecification.id', 'specifications.title as parent', 'subspecifications.title as subspec')
 ->where('product_id', '=', $product->id)
 ->join('subspecifications', 'subspecifications.id', '=', 'product_subspecification.subspecification_id')
 ->join('specifications', 'specifications.id', '=', 'subspecifications.specification_id')
 ->get();
```

Then you could possibly get a result like:

```
{#3106 ▼
  +"id": 8
  +"subspec": "Xplorer 5500M"
  +"parent": "Keyboard"
}
```